# JGit: Use TreeWalk to get content of file

Tags: java, git, jgit

I want to get content of files. The input is the revision. 
How I can get content of files that in working directory or stage area
for example if I have file 'Test' with value '1'
If I did change to '2' and stage the file
now I did another change on the same file to '3'
Now I have two files one stage and one is not. How I can get the content of the file.

In the code I found I can get the information only for the commit ID or HEAD

```
try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(getRepository())) {
    RevCommit revCommit = revWalk.parseCommit(revision);
    RevTree tree = revCommit.getTree();

    try (TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(getRepository())) {
        treeWalk.addTree(tree);
        treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
        treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create(request.getFile()));
        if (!treeWalk.next()) { 
          //error
        }
        ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
        ObjectLoader loader = repository.open(objectId);
        content = new String(loader.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to traverse over the entries of the staging area, you need to get hold of the repository's `DirCache`. This class represents the staging area.

For example:

```java
DirCache index = repository.lockDirCache();
try {
  // create treeWwalk
  treeWalk.addTree( new DirCacheIterator( index ) )
  // iterate over treeWalk
} finally {
  index.unlock();
}
```

Once you have obtained a locked dir cache, it can be added to the tree walk. Don't forget to unlock the dir cache as soon as it is not needed any longer.

In the same way as in your code snippet, you can use `treeWalk.getObjectId( 0 )` to return the blob id of the current entry.

Comment: what did you meant - Don't forget to unlock the dir cache as soon as it is not needed any longer. ?

Comment: what is the different between the getObjectId and the treeWalk ? what is better ? how to work with the treeWalk in this case?

Comment: Like the name implies `lockDirCache()` locks the dir cache for use by others and therefore you need to release this lock as soon as possible.

Comment: I found an example that they get the DirCache and then call to getObjectID without the tree. what is the different ?like        DirCache cache = db.readDirCache();
  DirCacheEntry entry = cache.getEntry(pattern);
  if (entry == null) {
   return null;
  }
  ObjectId blobId = entry.getObjectId();

Comment: Just re-use your `try (TreeWalk`... code but instead of `treeWalk.addTree( tree )` add the dir cache to the treeWalk.

Comment: I understood your comment but just to understand what is the different if I do the logic with treeWalkd or like in the example with the getEntry of the cache ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What have you tried to find the difference yourself? Which example uses getEntry?

Comment: Hi If I use TreeWalk and I added several tree to addTree.  How I can know the state of the file if it is staging or commit or HEAD or just modify ?

Comment: In your case, you shouldn't be adding more than one tree to the TreeWalk. The index tree should be added **instead** of the commit tree. Generally speaking, however, the index given in `getObjectId()` determines of which tree the object id is obtained from.